# Making a Simple Timer

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

I need to make a 3 second coundown timer for a 'bomberman' style game i'm making in java. I want to make the bombs explode on a 3 second countdown but when I add a delay to the script I have, it delays the whole program. (Thread.sleep() does the same thing).

So I need a really simple example of a script that runs a main program with another thread that runs a 3 second timer.

I'm pretty new to java so don't use many fancy words without explanations!!!!!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class MainClass extends JFrame implements KeyListener{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MainClass(){     
        super("WaterBalloonWars");
        JPanel panel=new JPanel(new GridLayout(width,height));
        myGrid = new JPanel[width][height];
        Border border=BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY, 1);   
        for(int r=0;r<width-1;r++){
            for(int c=0;c<height-1;c++){
                double randNum = Math.random();
                myGrid[c][r] = new JPanel();
                myGrid[c][r].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                myGrid[c][r].setBorder(border);
                if(randNum<=0.65){
                    myGrid[c][r].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                }
                if((r & 1)==1){
                    if((c & 1)==1){
                        myGrid[c][r].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    }                   
                }

                panel.add(myGrid[c][r]);            
                            }
        }               
        myGrid [0][0].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        myGrid [0][1].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        myGrid [1][0].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        myGrid [2][0].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        myGrid [0][2].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        myGrid [10][10].setBackground(Color.RED);
        myGrid [10][9].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        myGrid [9][10].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        myGrid [8][10].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        myGrid [10][8].setBackground(Color.WHITE);  
        super.setContentPane(panel);
        this.addKeyListener(new UKeyListener());
        this.addKeyListener(new DKeyListener());  
        this.addKeyListener(new LKeyListener()); 
        this.addKeyListener(new RKeyListener());
        this.addKeyListener(new ShiftKeyListener());
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        }

    class ShiftKeyListener implements KeyListener{
        @Override 
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) { 
            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT) {  
               plantBomb(Color.red);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {   

        }
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {          
        }
    }

    class UKeyListener implements KeyListener{        

        @Override 
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) { 
            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {  
               redMove(1);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {   

        }
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {          
        }
       }
    class DKeyListener implements KeyListener{        
        @Override 
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) { 
            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {  
               redMove(2);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {   

        }
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {          
        }
    }   
    class LKeyListener implements KeyListener{        
        @Override 
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) { 
            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {  
               redMove(3);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {   

        }
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {          
        }
    }
    class RKeyListener implements KeyListener{        
        @Override 
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) { 
            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {  
               redMove(4);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {   

        }
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {          
        }
    }
        public void plantBomb(Color color){     
            if(color.equals(Color.red)){
                rbombx=rx;
                rbomby=ry;
                myGrid[rbombx][rbomby].setBackground(Color.orange);
                redBombPlaced=true; 
                explode(Color.red,2,rbombx,rbomby);

            }
            if(color.equals(Color.blue)){

            }
        }
    public void explode(Color color,int power,int x,int y){
```

//THIS IS THE PART THAT I WANT THE TIMER TO GO

```
        boolean ublock=false;
        boolean dblock=false;
        boolean lblock=false;
        boolean rblock=false;
        for(int i=1;i<=power;i++){
            if(!rblock&&(x+i)<=10){
                if(myGrid[x+i][y].getBackground().equals(Color.black)){
                    rblock=true;                    
                }else{myGrid[x+i][y].setBackground(Color.white);}
            }
            if (!lblock&&(x-i)>=0){
                if(myGrid[x-i][y].getBackground().equals(Color.black)){
                    lblock=true;                
                }else{myGrid[x-i][y].setBackground(Color.white);}
            }   
            if(!dblock&&(y+i)<=10){
                if(myGrid[x][y+i].getBackground().equals(Color.black)){
                    dblock=true;
                }else{myGrid[x][y+i].setBackground(Color.white);}
            }
            if(!ublock&&(y-i)>=0){
                if(myGrid[x][y-i].getBackground().equals(Color.black)){
                    ublock=true;
                }else{myGrid[x][y-i].setBackground(Color.white);}
            }

            if(color.equals(Color.red)){
                redBombPlaced=false;
            }
        }
    }


    public void redMove(int direction){//1=up 2=down 3=left 4=right
        if(direction==1){
            if(ry-1!=-1){
            if(myGrid[rx][ry-1].getBackground()==(Color.BLACK)||myGrid[rx][ry-1].getBackground()==(Color.GRAY)||ry-1==-1){  
            }else{
                ry--;           
                myGrid[rx][ry].setBackground(Color.red);
                if(redBombPlaced){
                    redBombPlaced=false;
                }else{
                    myGrid[rx][ry+1].setBackground(Color.white);
                }
            }
            }
        }
        if(direction==2){
            if(ry+1!=11){
            if(myGrid[rx][ry+1].getBackground()==(Color.BLACK)||myGrid[rx][ry+1].getBackground()==(Color.GRAY)||ry+1>11){   
            }else{
            ry++;
            myGrid[rx][ry].setBackground(Color.red);
            if(redBombPlaced){
                redBombPlaced=false;
            }else{
                myGrid[rx][ry-1].setBackground(Color.white);
            }
            }
            }
        }
        if(direction==3){
            if(rx-1!=-1){
            if(myGrid[rx-1][ry].getBackground()==(Color.BLACK)||myGrid[rx-1][ry].getBackground()==(Color.GRAY)||rx-1==-1){
            }else{
            rx--;
            myGrid[rx][ry].setBackground(Color.red);
            if(redBombPlaced){
                redBombPlaced=false;
            }else{
                myGrid[rx+1][ry].setBackground(Color.white);
            }
            }
            }
        }
        if(direction==4){
            if(rx+1!=11){
                if(myGrid[rx+1][ry].getBackground()==(Color.BLACK)||myGrid[rx+1][ry].getBackground()==(Color.GRAY)||rx+1==11){
                }else{
                    rx++;
                    myGrid[rx][ry].setBackground(Color.red);
                    if(redBombPlaced){
                        redBombPlaced=false;
                    }else{
                        myGrid[rx-1][ry].setBackground(Color.white);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void centerFrame(){
        Dimension screen=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int drawAtX=screen.width/2 - super.getWidth() / 2;
        int drawAtY=screen.height/2 - super.getHeight() / 2;
        super.setLocation(drawAtX-50,drawAtY-50);
    }
    private JPanel [][] myGrid;
    private int width=12;
    private int height=12;  
    private int rx=10;
    private int ry=10;
    int rbombx=0;
    int rbomby=0;
    private boolean redBombPlaced=false;
    private boolean blueBombPlaced=false;
    /*public static void main(String[] args){
        MainClass frame = new MainClass();
        frame.setSize(600,600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.centerFrame();
    }*/
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {      
    }
}
```

Don't comment on my coding, it probably makes you cringe but that's ok,

Comment: Can you show some code?  Are you actually creating a separate thread for the timer?

Comment: Updated my original post

Answer (score 1):

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            bombs.explode();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can Create a Timer inside a thread using TimerTask.

Using the `Thread.sleep` will actually put your Main Thread to the `block state`.

**example:**

```
    public class TimerBomb {
  Toolkit toolkit;

  Timer timer;

  public TimerBomb(int seconds) {
    toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new RemindTask (), seconds * 1000);
  }

  class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
      System.out.println("3 second is up");
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("About to schedule task.");
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new TimerBomb(3);


        }
    });
    t.start();
    System.out.println("Task scheduled.");
  }
}
```